# Problem with array[np.argwhere(array==value)]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Taking `np.argwhere` as a list of coordinates in 2d leads to a wrong result.
For instance:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0], [2, 3, 0]])
coordinates = np.argwhere(array==1)
array[coordinates] = 3
print(array)
```

Gives:

```
[[3 3 3]
 [2 0 0]
 [3 3 3]]
```

even though only the values `1` should be changed.

Comment: Use np.where instead

Comment: or omit it entirely if you don't need the actual coordinates

Comment: You could also use `array[array == 1] = 3` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [163]: array = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0], [2, 3, 0]])   
In [164]: array
Out[164]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 0]])   
In [165]: array==1
Out[165]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

`np.where/nonzero` finds the coordinates of the True values, giving a tuple of arrays:

```
In [166]: np.nonzero(array==1)
Out[166]: (array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

That tuple can be used - as is - to index the array:

```
In [167]: array[np.nonzero(array==1)]
Out[167]: array([1, 1])
```

`argwhere` returns the same values, but as 2d array, one column per dimension:

```
In [168]: np.argwhere(array==1)
Out[168]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

It is wrong to use it as an index:

```
In [169]: array[np.argwhere(array==1),:]
Out[169]: 
array([[[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [2, 3, 0]]])
```

I added the `:` to show more clearly that it is just indexing the first dimension of `array`, not both as done with the tuple of arrays in [167].

To use `argwhere` to index the array we have to do:

```
In [170]: x = np.argwhere(array==1)
In [171]: x
Out[171]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Apply each column separately to the dimensions:

```
In [172]: array[x[:,0], x[:,1]]
Out[172]: array([1, 1])
```

`argwhere` is more useful if you want to iterate through the nonzero elements:

```
In [173]: for i in x:
     ...:     print(array[tuple(i)])
     ...:     
1
1
```

But as commented, you don't need the `where/argwhere` step; just use the boolean array as index

```
In [174]: array[array==1]
Out[174]: array([1, 1])
```